# Program won't display output correctly

Tags: java, output

I'm writing a program that is supposed to display the output based off of some numbers that are typed in. I'm ending up with an output and it is completely blank, and none of the calculations are being performed

```
/**
* 
* @NMATA003PA1.java
* @author Nicholas Mata
* @version 1.00 2015/09/25
* 
* Program Purpose: This program controls whether a customer can calculate the cost of his/her stock purchases.
* 
*/

import java.util.Scanner; //Scanner is imported to capture user input
import java.util.Calendar;//Calendare is imported to reflect the current date when necessary

public class MataN003PA1

{
    public static void main(String[] args)//Customer will be able to calculate costs of multiple trades
    {
        String customerName = "", date = "";//Customer name and date are declared as Strings
        int shares = 0, noOfStocks = 0;//shares and noOfShares are declared as integers, they are set to zero
        double sharePrice = 0, stockCost = 0, commission = 0, totalCost = 0, onlineFee = 0, totalStockCost = 0, totalCommissions = 0, totalOnlineFees = 0; 
        /**
        * sharePrice, stockCost, commission, totalCost, onlineFee, totalStockCost, totalCommissions, totalOnline Fees are declared
        * as double, they are also set to zero
        */
        char onlineTrade = ' ', brokerAssisted = ' ', another = ' '; // onlineTrade and brokerAssisted are declared as char variables, set to blank
        Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance(); //dateTime is declared

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("%nYEE-TRADE, INC. - The Wild West of Electronic Trading"
        +"%n%nWelcome to Yee-Trade's stock purchase calculator.%n");

        System.out.printf("%n%nWhat is your name?  ");
        customerName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("%nDo you want to calculate your stock purchases?  Enter 'Y' or 'N' to exit:  ");
        another = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

        while (Character.toUpperCase(another) == 'Y')
        {
            noOfStocks = noOfStocks + 1;

            System.out.printf("%nHow many shares did you purchase?  ");
            shares = input.nextInt();

            System.out.printf("%nWhat is the price per share?  ");
            sharePrice = input.nextDouble();
            input.nextLine();

            stockCost = shares * sharePrice;
            totalStockCost = totalStockCost + stockCost;
            totalCost = totalCost + stockCost;

            System.out.printf("%nIs this an online trade?  Enter 'Y' or 'N':  ");
            onlineTrade = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

            if (Character.toUpperCase(onlineTrade) == 'Y')
            {
                onlineFee = 5.95;
                totalOnlineFees = totalOnlineFees + onlineFee;
                totalCost = totalCost + onlineFee;
            }//END if_1
            else
            {
                System.out.printf("%nIs this a broker assisted trade?  Enter 'Y' or 'N':  ");
                brokerAssisted = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

                if (Character.toUpperCase(brokerAssisted) == 'Y')
                {
                    commission = stockCost * .02;
                    totalCommissions = totalCommissions + commission;
                    totalCost = totalCost + commission;

                }//END if_2
                else
                {
                    System.out.printf("%nINVALID TRADE TYPE!  %n");
                    noOfStocks = noOfStocks - 1;
                    totalStockCost = totalStockCost - stockCost;
                    totalCost = totalCost - stockCost;
                }//end else_2
            }//end else_1

            System.out.printf("%nEnter 'Y' to calculate the cost of another stock purchase or 'N' to exit:  ");
            another = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

        }//END WHILE LOOP

        if (noOfStocks > 0);
        { 
            System.out.printf("%nYEE-TRADE, INC."
            +"%nTOTAL COST OF STOCK PURCHASES"
            +"%nFOR %s", customerName);
            System.out.printf("%nAS OF ");
            System.out.printf("%1$TB %1$Td, %1$TY%n", dateTime);
            System.out.printf("%nTotal Stock Cost:  $", totalStockCost);
            System.out.printf("%nTotal Online Fees:  $", totalOnlineFees);
            System.out.printf("%nTotal Commissions:  $", totalCommissions);
            System.out.printf("%n%nTOTAL COST:  $", totalCost);

        }//END if_3

        System.out.printf("%nThank you for using Yee-Trade's stock purchase calculator!  ");

        noOfStocks = 0;



        System.exit(0);}//END MAIN
}//END CLASS
```

Comment: is there any exception

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, you should check out this page : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: and what exactly is the output?

Answer (score 1):

You should not always try to `format` the output if it is not necessary.

Here's your problem :

```
        System.out.printf("%nAS OF ");
        System.out.printf("%1$TB %1$Td, %1$TY%n", dateTime);
        System.out.printf("%nTotal Stock Cost:  $" + totalStockCost);
        System.out.printf("%nTotal Online Fees:  $", totalOnlineFees);
        System.out.printf("%nTotal Commissions:  $", totalCommissions);
        System.out.printf("%n%nTOTAL COST:  $", totalCost);
```

You'll have to replace most of these with the following

```
        System.out.printf("%nAS OF ");
        System.out.printf("%1$TB %1$Td, %1$TY%n", dateTime);
        System.out.println("Total Stock Cost:  $" + totalStockCost);
        System.out.println("Total Online Fees:  $" + totalOnlineFees);
        System.out.println("Total Commissions:  $" + totalCommissions);
        System.out.println("TOTAL COST:  $" + totalCost);
```

Here is the output I get :

```
YEE-TRADE, INC. - The Wild West of Electronic Trading

    Welcome to Yee-Trade's stock purchase calculator.


    What is your name?  Yassin

    Do you want to calculate your stock purchases?  Enter 'Y' or 'N' to exit:  Y

    How many shares did you purchase?  50

    What is the price per share?  50

    Is this an online trade?  Enter 'Y' or 'N':  Y

    Enter 'Y' to calculate the cost of another stock purchase or 'N' to exit:  N

    YEE-TRADE, INC.
    TOTAL COST OF STOCK PURCHASES
    FOR Yassin
    AS OF OCTOBRE 04, 2015
    Total Stock Cost:  $2500.0
    Total Online Fees:  $5.95
    Total Commissions:  $0.0
    TOTAL COST:  $2505.95

    Thank you for suing Yee-Trade's stock purchase calculator!
```